# how to Debug using breakpoint in protractor cucumber framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, protractor, cucumber

I'm working in Protractor Cucumber node js framework for test automation.  How do we debug using break point in this framework?  Have any one used this option in your project?  we are able to read variable in debug window using repl. But we want to debug using break point like how we do in Visual studio because we want to check the action performed during automation. As of now, we use log to track the flow in high level.

Comment: The [`protractor` docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) suggest using `browser.debugger();` to insert breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can do log level debugging

console.log("Completed " + JSON.stringify(obj));